# Empty arc in Datamaps

Tags: d3.js, datamaps

When attempting to draw arcs on a map from Datamaps, as shown here: https://datamaps.github.io/

I get an empty arc, using the following code and shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/yausern/qbgewhss/1/

```
var map = new Datamap(
    {
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        fills: {
            defaultFill: "#ABDDA4",
            win: '#0fa0fa'
        },
        data: {
            'CHN': { fillKey: 'win' },
            'SWE': { fillKey: 'win' },

        }
    }
);
map.arc(
    [
        {
            origin: 'CHN',
            destination: 'SWE',
            options: {
                strokeWidth: 2,
                strokeColor: 'rgba(100, 10, 200, 0.4)',
                greatArc: true
            }

        }
    ],
    {
        strokeWidth: 1, arcSharpness: 1.4
    }

)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when using the high resolution version found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/master/dist/datamaps.world.hires.min.js

I do not get this to work in JSFiddle though, getting the following error message in the console:

`Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/master/dist/datamaps.world.hires.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

When I download the script and refer to it locally, it works when using Python 3's http.server

Answer (score 0):

According to the API, it seems that the arcs plugin accepts the country name. I tried several things, from using `scope:'world'` to referencing the plugin, but no success.

Anyway, this may not sound as a solution to you, but you can always use latitude and longitude:

```
{
  origin: {
      latitude: 60.1282,
      longitude: 18.6435
  },
  destination: {
      latitude: 35.8617,
      longitude: 104.1954
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/59seachL/

Comment: Thanks for your input, it starts to sound like a bug doesn't it?

Comment: I found a solution, check my answer

Comment: Good to know! So, it seems like a bug indeed.